# Why did Scipy fit this curve so badly?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit this function to some data

This is my function:

```
def first_deriv(xlist, L, k, x0):
    return [k*L*(math.e**(-k*(x+x0)))/(1+math.e**(-k*(x+x0)))**2 for x in xlist]
```

This is how the function looks, so I expected to get a pretty good fitting.
[image: How the function looks]

This is the code to fit the function to the data

```
popt = curve_fit(first_deriv, list(range(len(data))), data, bounds=((0, -np.inf, -np.inf), (10**(9), +np.inf, 0)), maxfev=10000)
```

And this is how I am plotting it:

```
xdata = list(np.linspace(-100, 100, 2000))    
plt.scatter(xdata, first_deriv(xdata, popt[0][0], popt[0][1], popt[0][2]), s=1)
```

The bounds are there to make the answer reasonable, but even if I make all the bounds infinite, it still gives a terrible fit.

This is the terrible fitting

[image: The bad fit]

I'm surprised how curve_fit seems to totally screw it up.
Can someone please explain why?

Comment: what is the `data` variable? How is it generated? I can't run your code as it is above, perhaps you could provide a MWE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're passing in a different set of x-values to the fit vs the plot...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with your example.

**A trivial problem**

`curve_fit` expects the [values of the independent variable as the second argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), whereas the code above gives `list(range(len(data))`, which will produce integer x values from 0 to however long `data` is. You'll notice that your scatter plot points only go up to ~50. My guess is that this is why.

Instead you should give a list of the values of the independent variable at the points where `data` was observed. Depending on how `data` is generated/collected (you don't provide this information in your question), this might be `xdata`.

I am also a little confused as to how the second plot fits in with the first. The y scale doesn't seem to match up for the blue line. My guess is that the plots were generated from different examples for different parameter values. I'll ignore them.

**The real problem**

Not all optimisation methods are equally suited to all problems. `curve_fit` is capable of using 3 methods, `'lm`, `'trf'` and `'dogbox'`. The default is `lm`, for the [Levenberg–Marquardt method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm), *unless* bounds are given, in which case `'trf'` is used instead, which is a [Trust Region method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_region).

Playing with the example a bit, I found that `'lm'` performed well, while `'trf'` did not.

For example, take the following code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def first_deriv(xlist, L, k, x0):
    return [k*L*(math.e**(-k*(x+x0)))/(1+math.e**(-k*(x+x0)))**2 for x in xlist]

xdata = list(np.linspace(-100, 100, 2000))
real_parameters = (320000.0, 0.1, -30.0)

fakedata = first_deriv(xdata, *real_parameters)
plt.plot(xdata, fakedata)
```

Which produces the curve in your example above (ish):
[image]

A comparison of the 3 methods confirms that `'lm'` is looking the best, and recovers the original parameters:

```
lm_parameters = curve_fit(first_deriv, xdata, fakedata)[0]
trf_parameters = curve_fit(first_deriv, xdata, fakedata, method='trf')[0]
dogbox_parameters = curve_fit(first_deriv, xdata, fakedata, method='dogbox')[0]

plt.scatter(xdata, first_deriv(xdata, *lm_parameters), s=1, label='lm')
plt.scatter(xdata, first_deriv(xdata, *trf_parameters), s=1, label='trf')
plt.scatter(xdata, first_deriv(xdata, *dogbox_parameters), s=1, label='dogbox')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

An interesting question (that perhaps deserves its own post) is why this is the case. While I am unqualified to make a precise mathematical argument, playing with the parameters of your function suggests some rough ideas.

For example, 'broadening the peak' of your function seems to allow all methods to perform well.
[image]
[image]

No doubt changing the parameters has altered the 'fitness landscape' in such a way to allow the trust region methods to succeed.

It is also possible that certain parameters of the `'trf'` and `'dogbox'` methods themselves might produce better results. This would require a more in-depth knowledge of the methods.

Having said that, `'lm'` seems to be the best method for this particular problem. It is always important to be aware of which method you are using, and to experiment with different ones for each new problem, especially if you are getting bad results.

Comment: Initial guess matters a lot here. For a gaussian, I would recommend Jean Jacquelin's methodology.

Comment: Yes, there is for sure a lot more to it than I've written here. In this case, lm seems to do fine with the default initial guess, although there are benefits to using a different initial guess in other circumstances, I'm sure. It deserves its own post, I think

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Optimization procedures can get trapped in local maxima (when any change to the parameters would first make the fit worse before it would get better). To avoid this problem (and to speed up the computations), [scipy.optimize.curve_fit()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) allows you to specify your best guesses for the parameters with the `p0` keyword argument.

So you should pass the parameter values you used for your plot of the function above to `curve_fit()` as a starting point.